# What is the payout date for commercial applications?

Tags: software-center, application-development, commercial

What date are commercial developers paid for their sales? I thought it was quarterly, but it's been about 4 months since my first sale and I haven't been paid.

NOTE: I sent canonical an email, I'll post an answer when I get a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zoopster noted, I needed to supply my last name, however, I don't think I got an email about it until my inquiry.

The issue has been resolved now that all required personal information is supplied.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the [Developer Agreement](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/tos/), payments happen within 30 days of the end of every calendar quarter. If it has been 2 calendar quarters since payment it is likely that we sent you an email requesting information to which you did not respond or the only charge was due to our end to end testing of your app.

You can send me an email at john dot pugh at canonical.com with the application name and I can ensure we have the proper information to process your payment.